# Nginx Rewrite: change only index location?

Tags: nginx, url-rewriting

How can I send a user to a new location, only if the user have no URI? I am trying the follow, but it does not works... it always send me to /newlocation

```
rewrite ^/$ http://www.domain.com/newlocation permanent;
rewrite ^/(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/$1 permanent;
```

So basically, what I need is:

If the user writes on browser www.domain.org it sends to www.domain.com/newlocation
If the user writes on browser www.domain.org/something it sends to www.domain.com/something

Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

I'm not sure why your current approach isn't working.  ^/$ should only match /.  Maybe it's something else it the current config.  Here's a server that should do what you want.

```
server {
  server_name www.domain.org;

  # Only match requests for /
  location = / {
    rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com/newlocation permanent;
  }

  # Match everything else
  location / {
    rewrite ^ http://www.domain.com$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}
```

Comment: It takes me some time to make out there is one more "=" in the first expression